# How to split Numeric part from alphanumeric string in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

I have stored a value in string in this format `12.5PerRs`. I want to separate this string as `12.5`. for this i have tried this code

```
string s4 = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Rate"]).Value.ToString();
string numbers = "";
string alpha = "";
foreach (char c in s4)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        numbers = numbers + c;
    }
    else if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        alpha = alpha + c;
    }
}
```

Suppose `string s4="12.5RsPer`  has this value but with this code that i have implemented, i am getting `125` as result, as this is not expected.

What should i do to split this value in desired way?

Answer (score 1):

A dot is not a letter, that's why this returns false: `Char.IsLetter('.')`. It's a punctuation character which is a different category. You'd need `Char.IsPunctuation('.')`. But different cultures use different decimal separators so this approach is not very robust.

So you could use this method:

```
public static decimal? ExtractNumberFromStart(string input, NumberFormatInfo nfi = null)
{
    if (nfi == null) nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    char sep = nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]; // no culture uses multiple characters as separator
    var numberPart = input.TrimStart().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == sep);
    decimal dec;
    if (decimal.TryParse(string.Concat(numberPart), NumberStyles.Number, nfi, out dec))
        return dec;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Your sample:

```
string input = "12.5PerRs";
decimal? dec = ExtractNumberFromStart(input);
if (dec.HasValue)
{
    string number = dec.ToString();                // 12.5
    string alpha = input.Substring(number.Length); // PerRs
}
```

Comment: +1 nice example to get the currency tag from the string value if OP has specified currency symbol to current culture.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, This one will match every numberDotNumber on the string.

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"([1-9])+(\.)+([1-9])");
 Match match = regex.Match(s);
 if (match.Success)
 {
    value = decimal.Parse(match.Value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help?

```
if (Char.IsDigit(c) || (c == ".") || (c == ","))
{
  numbers += c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
string value = "125.5PerRs";
Decimal dValue = 0;
for (int i=0; i<value.Length;i++)
{
   if (!Char.IsDigit(value[i]) && value[i] != '.')
   {
     dValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value.Substring(0,i));
     break;
   }
}
```

then just take the value after the decimal value from string to get alpha value.

```
string alpha = value.Substring(dValue.ToString().Length);
```